# Are you considered a stateless person if you lose your passport?

Tags: stateless-persons

My question is about someone who's traveling and loses their passport on foreign ground. After restoring, the new passport came from his own country, but was collected from the embassy in the foreign state. The foreign state's name is in the *place of issue* column in this new passport.

In that situation, is the person considered a stateless person?

Comment: Your question is a little hard to understand.  Let's say the person has a passport from Country A, so he's a citizen of A.  His passport is stolen in Country B, then Embassy of A in B gives him a new one, and it has "Country B" as Place of Issue?  And you're asking if this makes him stateless?

Comment: Are you _nameless_ if you lose your business cards?

Answer (score 10):

No.  The country issuing the passport is the passport bearer's country of citizenship.  The passport was issued under the authority of that country, and it certifies that the country recognizes the bearer as a national of that country.  The bearer of the passport is therefore not stateless.

The *place of issue* of a passport is just that: the location of the office that issued the passport.  It is quite common for foreign diplomatic missions to issue passports to their citizens abroad, and when that happens, the passport's place of issue will usually reflect the fact that the passport was issued in a country other than the one on whose authority it was issued.

To say this more concretely: A passport issued by the embassy of Aliceland located in the country of Bobistan will often say that it was issued *in* Bobistan.  But it was still issued *by* Aliceland, and the person named in the passport is still a national of Aliceland.

See also [Which country issued my passport if I received it at a consulate abroad?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/99783/19400)

Answer (score 10):

No.

[A stateless person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statelessness) has no nationality. This often can happen if the country someone was a citizen of ceases to exist or disavows a claim to citizenship for discriminatory reasons, leaving them with no recognized citizenship from any state.

None of that is the same thing as losing your passport. If I'm a citizen of, say, France, and I lose my passport, I'm still a French citizen; I just happen to be a French citizen who is not currently in possession of a passport. I can go to the proper French authorities and get a new passport. A stateless person cannot do that, because they're not recognized as a citizen of any country.